# Why Vue treats unspecified boolean props as false?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Please see this example

If I have a component like this:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="on">
    Hello
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    on: Boolean
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.on)
  }
};
</script>
```

And then I render that component and specify nothing on the prop

```
<template>
  <div >
    <HelloWorld/>
  </div>
</template>
```

This will output `false` instead of `undefined`?

Why is that?

Is there anyway I can detect if people didn't specify the prop, so I can use lodash `_.isBoolean` to detect it?

Currently, the only way I know is manually set the default to `undefined`.

Comment: why not put a default value of it ?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the only way.

Comment: *Why is that?* [Apparently for "convenience"](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8704). The way you know is the right way. Otherwise, make it `required` if you don't want people to forget about it.

Comment: Because undefined is falsey—standard JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a default value on it and check if the value is still the same then the user didn't pass a prop, but there are instance where  you can't really compare your value to its default, like if the prop is a function.

You could have `this.$options.propsData` inside of your component. If the prop is present here, the user has explicitly set it; default values aren't shown in.

Comment: Thank you, but propsData's typing is `object`, not friendly for Vue TypeScript, such a pity.